# Problems installing RMagick with Paperclip in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, rubygems, rmagick

I'm trying to use paperclip in rails and when I'm doing the "bundle install" I'm getting the following error:

Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in /usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/seanhinton/.rvm/bin

What I'm wondering is how do I install RMagick (is that what I need?) on my machine (it's OSX 10.6)?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RMagick is a ruby adapter for ImageMagick. Getting ImageMagick is a huge pain, and it doesn't come on your computer by default. Here's the easiest way to get it:

1. [Get Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (Mac OS Package Manager).
2. In terminal, run `brew install imagemagick`.
3. Now add `gem 'rmagick'` to your Gemfile. (in your application root directory)
4. Finally, in terminal, run `bundle install`.

That's it. Note that the imagemagick installer may take a while.

Comment: That's brilliant! Cheers. Exactly what I needed. Easy when you know how.