# Paperclip Error: Filename not recognized by the 'identify' command - ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

```
image/png
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/0f/hgplttnd7dg6q9m62qtbnpn00000gn/T/stream20120120-99159-ji1e70.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

This is the model for `Uploads`

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_voteable
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => {  :thumb => "64x64" },
                :storage => :s3,
            :s3_credentials => "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
            :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"

    validates :stage_id, :presence => true
    validates :name, :presence => true
    validates_attachment_presence :image                    
  validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 10.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/JPG']
```

I have heard that if I remove `:styles` it will work, but that defeats the purpose of using Paperclip. I need to be able to create the sized thumbnail on each image upload.

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem once on one of the servers, it turned out that ImageMagick was not installed.

Comment: Please, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12771707/1472432 The problem may be in using cocaine 0.4. Try downgrade to cocaine 0.3.2. Paperclip uses Cocaine, but new gem version use wrong identify command format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact happened to me, check [Problems installing RMagick with Paperclip in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576105/problems-installing-rmagick-with-paperclip-in-rails-3)

Need to install imagemagick (suggested with homebrew) and then include the gem 'rmagick'.

Comment: I am sure I have it installed. Didn't have the gem listed in my Gemfile though. How do I check to see if RMagick is installed?

Comment: That fixed it...Thanks. But that's SOO weird. Why would ImageMagick all of a sudden no longer be installed? This is a site I have been running for at least a year and ImageMagick was installed from the get-go. All of a sudden, in the last week or so, I had been having problems with the uploads. I wasn't sure what the deal was...so the truth is I didn't even think that it was ImageMagick - given that I had installed it long ago.

Any reason why this would surface right now?

Comment: Do "gem list" to check which gems are you using. If you didn't have RMagick in the Gemfile, i don't know if the crop functionality would work properly.